# What does the operator "2>>" do in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, sh

I read the following code from [c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex28.html](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex28.html)

```
echo "Running unit tests:"

for i in tests/*_tests
do
    if test -f $i
    then
        if $VALGRIND ./$i 2>> tests/tests.log
        then
            echo $i PASS
        else
            echo "ERROR in test $i: here's tests/tests.log"
            echo "------"
            tail tests/tests.log
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done

echo ""
```

What does the operator "2>>" do in shell scripting?

Also, before I ask this question, I have tested it out on the command line and this is what I got:

```
~/Projects/test> if 0 2>> hello.txt; then echo "0"; else echo "?"; fi
?
~/Projects/test> if 1 2>> hello.txt; then echo "0"; else echo "?"; fi
?
~/Projects/test> if 108230284 2>> hello.txt; then echo "0"; else echo "?"; fi
?
~/Projects/test> if 0 2>> hello.txt; then echo "0"; else echo "?"; fi
?

~/Projects/test> cat hello.txt
-bash: 0: command not found
-bash: 1: command not found
-bash: 108230284: command not found
-bash: 0: command not found
```

Comment: See : http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/comparison-ops.html\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The >> operator generally enables output redirection to a file and *appending* to it instead of replacing it (the > operator replaces).

A number in front of any redirection operator defines the stream number to be redirected, in this case `stderr`.

So `some-command 2>> file` appends the `stderr`-outputs of `some-command` to the file `file`.

By the way: `2>>&1` redirects the content of `stderr` to the same stream as `stdout`, this is often used to see both streams in a single piped command:

```
some-command 2>&1 | less
```

This will pipe both `stderr` and `stdout` to `less`, since the `2>&1` mixes in the `stderr` to the `stdout` stream that is then piped to `less`.

The `if` in your example is unrelated to the `2>>`, it will simply evaluate the return value of `valgrind`.